# Rendering query best practice rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, render

I have a model for Contracts that has a field called "totalAward". In my index.html.erb view I have the following code:

```
<p> Total Award Amount: <td><%= number_to_currency(Contract.sum('awardAmount')) %></td>     </p>
```

I'm fairly certain it's not a best practice for me to do a database call in the view, but I am not sure how to do it in the controller or the model in a way that I can render it in the view. Could someone help me with how make that database call in the controller or the model?

Thanks!

Comment: what do you have in your controller's index action?

Comment: I have:

      def index
        @contracts = Contract.all
      end

Comment: so `totalAward` is an attribute of `Contract`. what is `sum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instance variable (`@contracts`) from your controller will give you access to the attributes of your model. I believe you want to use ActiveRecord's [sum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum) method. Here is how you can use it in your view:

```
<%= @contracts.sum(:totalAward) %>
```

This way, you are not querying the db in your views. but you have access to the instance variable (@contracts) in your controller which holds a collection of all of your contracts.

Answer (score 1):

Further to `Wali Ali`, you will be best sticking to the [MVC programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) (the basis of Rails). This means you need to keep your data-allocation (set variables) in your `controller`, and data storage in your `models`

I would use a [instance method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/):

```
#app/models/contract.rb
Class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
    def total
        sum(:totalAward)
    end
end
```

This will allow you to perform things like this:

```
#app/controllers/contracts_controller.rb
Class ContractsController < ApplicationController
    def index
       @contracts = Contract.all #-> @contracts.total for all
       @contracts = Contract.where(some: value) #-> @contracts.total for these items
    end
end
```